# Python SymPy Block Matrix TypeError

Tags: python, matrix, block, sympy

I am using the following code, but it's producing a TypeError (Data type not understood) for the last line (block matrix Z). I am new to SymPy. Could someone please point out my mistake?

```
import sympy as sp

from IPython.display import display

X = sp.Matrix([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])

i = sp.Matrix([[1], [1], [1]])

display(i, X)

Z = sp.BlockMatrix([i.T*i, i.T*X], [X.T*i, X.T*X])
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument should be a list of lists:

```
Z = sp.BlockMatrix([[i.T*i, i.T*X], [X.T*i, X.T*X]])

Z:
⎡[3]   [6  6  6]  ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢⎡6⎤  ⎡14  14  14⎤⎥
⎢⎢ ⎥  ⎢          ⎥⎥
⎢⎢6⎥  ⎢14  14  14⎥⎥
⎢⎢ ⎥  ⎢          ⎥⎥
⎣⎣6⎦  ⎣14  14  14⎦⎦
```